# Is "e.force:closeQuickAction" no longer supported in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction

I have witnessed a strange issue today, when I observed that my Salesforce instance has been recently upgraded. All my lightning components which were using "e.force:closeQuickAction" to close the quick action, are no longer working. Is this something deprecated by Salesforce recently? If yes, then what is the workaround?

Component :

```
 <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">

    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}" class="slds-m-top--medium" />


</aura:component>
```

Controller :

```
    ({
    handleCancel: function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:closeQuickAction/documentation) doesn't say its deprecated, maybe you had used it in an unsupported way? Could you please edit your question with a minimal version of code so as we can replicate the behavior?

Comment: @Raul, I have used it in various contexts, and it was working since years. It happened today only, that I had witnessed an update in my Salesforce instance, and observed that this behaviour is not working. I have uploaded a most basic version, which I used to troubleshoot the things, but even this basic thing is not working.

Comment: Can you try putting the event into a variable and calling `.fire()` on that variable instead of one-lining it?

Comment: @DrewKennedy, tried that as well!

Comment: Could possibly be a bug with the platform. Wouldn't be the first time a new release has broken existing features. I'd create a case with Salesforce if you can.

Comment: @DrewKennedy, seems like that. One of my own dev org is having the older version, and that is working absolutely fine as expected.

Comment: Yes the same issue is for me in console apps

Comment: just wait for 1 week, salesforce release upgraded every week for bugs and enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

After Winter 20 release, force:closeQuickAction event has stopped working in Lightning Console Apps

Please check known issue : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Yn18QAC

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("DESKTOP uiModal forceModal");
element.forEach(function(e, t) {
    $A.util.addClass(e, 'slds-hide');
});